# RRDTool: Cannot plot line or area (plot empty)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, rrdtool

I've been trying to get to grips with RRDTool. Aside from the data acquisition and storage, I'm having trouble plotting anything at all.

Using it like this doesn't return anything, i.e. no png is created:

```
rrdtool graph graph.png --end now --start end-60 DEF:in=teams.rrd:in:AVERAGE LINE2:in#000000
```

The only way to get any output is to include something like GPRINT:

```
rrdtool graph graph.png --end now --start end-60 DEF:in=teams.rrd:in:AVERAGE LINE2:in#000000 GPRINT:in:AVERAGE:"%8.2lf %s Bytes"
```

But even then, the graph itself is empty, while the GPRINT prints the correct value. I've also tried my luck with plotting a constant value and using HRULE, to no avail. I've tried pretty much everything, manually specifying start and end as well as upper and lower limits.

This is on Debian Squeeze and Ubuntu 11.04.

**Update:**

Nevermind, I "solved" my problem. Turns out it had something to do with shell-expansion, and putting quotes around the "LINE:in:#000000" was sufficient. Stupid mistake.

Comment: It's considered acceptable to answer your own question in the answer area, if you figure out your own solution. It'll help others to see the question is already answered, and you'll get credit for answering a question!